# Spark Permanent Tables Management

Tags: apache-spark, etl

I have a question regarding best practices for managing permanent tables in Spark. I have been working previously with Databricks, and in that context, Databricks manages permanent tables so you do not have to 'create' or reference them each time a cluster is launched.

Let's say in a Spark cluster session, a permanent table is created with saveAsTable command using option to partition the table. Data is stored in S3 as parquet files.

Next day, a new cluster is created and it needs to access that table for different purposes:

- SQL query for exploratory analysis
- ETL process for appending a new chunk of data

What is the best way to make saved table available again as the same table with same structure/options/path? Maybe there a way to store hive metastore settings to be reused between spark sessions? Or maybe each time a spark cluster is created, I should do CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE with the correct options to tell the format (parquet), the partitioning and the path?

Furthermore, if I want to access those parquet files from another application, i.e. Apache Impala, is there a way to store and retrieve hive metastore information or the table has to be created again?

Thanks

Comment: Hive Metastore is backed by a SQL database -- MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, whatever -- even Derby if you don't have anything else *(the Derby JARs are included by default)*. So if you create a **separate VM** with a MySQL instance, you can start/stop your cluster at will while persisting the Metastore info; just make sure you start MySQL before the cluster, and stop it after the cluster stops. You can even use some AWS persistent DB solution, by the way.

Comment: Of course your cluster config will have to hard-code the connection params to your persistent Metastore, in `hive-site.xml`

Comment: And of course, with Spark 1.x you will have to use a version of Spark "with Hive support" and initiate a `HiveContext` instead of a generic `SqlContext`

Comment: Just one question
I understand that when I create new clusters, I should hard-code for each one the connection to the existing hive metastore using the property "hiveconf hive.metastore.warehouse.dir". Mentioned hive metastore can be i.e. in S3.

But I would need a bit more information about how to make the hive metastore persistent once the original cluster is down. Could you please ellaborate a bit more, or link to some literature?

Thanks

Comment: The "Warehouse dir" points to a filesystem, is the root directory to store **data files** _(well, it's the default root dir for new tables, but you can override it on a case by case basis)_. The Metastore is *(a)* a service backed by *(b)* a database, to manage a global **metadata** repository. So what's in the metadata? The list of tables, their definition (columns, format, partitions) and the actual location of the files.

Comment: Looks like you've got a lot a reading to do before that, but... the documentation for Hive server & client properties is here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

Comment: Thanks Samson, I have also found this veryinteresting one: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-dev-create-metastore-outside.html